# Power of Attorney Visa Application

Tags: immigration, travel, visa

I am a US Citizen currently in Bulgaria with my girlfriend. I was a previously a contractor in the Middle east and came to Bulgaria straight from my last contract - on a passport (90 days validity)

The problem: I am not allowed to apply for a long-stay (1 year) visa from within Bulgaria.

Possible Solution: Is it possible that I assign my father/mother as a Power of Attorney to submit my Visa application and relative documents to the Bulgarian consulate in the US?

Answer (score 1):

Applicants are required to appear in person at the consulate, and potentially to be interviewed, at least [if the application is submitted in New York](https://www.consulbulgaria-ny.org/visas.htm), so no, you cannot have anybody else submit your application.

You may be able to apply for a [residence permit](https://www.mvr.bg/migration/en/administrative-services/administrative-servces/issue-of-residence-permits-to-third-country-nationals) without leaving Bulgaria.  In EU terminology, residence permits and long-term visas are separate things but they have the same function.  The major difference is that you can apply for one only when you are in the country, and you can apply for the other only when you are outside the country.

Comment: Thank you, I was under the impression that a residence permit can only be obtained once the Type D (Long stay visa) was issued?

Comment: @TonyA I don't know about Bulgarian law, but in some Schengen countries it is not necessary to have a type D visa first if you are able to enter without a visa for a short stay (that is, have an "Annex II" passport).  In some Schengen countries, only a subset of Annex II nationalities are eligible to apply for a residence permit without a long-stay visa, but in those countries I know about, the US is always on the list.  It may also depend on the basis for your application.  On what grounds will you apply for a long-stay visa and/or residence permit?

Comment: @TonyA you may want to pursue this on [Expatriates.SE], where the question fits better than here.  You may also want to look at [Travel.SE], where visa questions abound, but questions about long-term visas are off topic there.  Still, there's a good deal of overlap and you may find useful information there.